# Read date using system locale and convert it to a new format

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I need to deploy an ASP.NET application written in C# to multiple servers and cannot be sure what the regional settings are.  How can I read the current date (DateTime.Today) into a DateTime variable using the server's locale and specify the format that I wish it to be in.  This way giving me a consistently formatted date that I can then manipulate as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Globalization;

DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
string local = now.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
string custom = now.ToString(new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

Note, that region settings only affects string representation, i.e. format, but not DateTime type itself!